# Msbuild 15 in sdk project raise an error: The element <Import> beneath element <When> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

In C# project using SDK style in vs2017 and msbuild 15, I try to import project based on condition using the following xml fragment:

```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <!--No <TargetFramework> element is defined, it's imported with Import Project element-->

     <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(PackId) == 'xyz'">
          <!-- it has <TargetFramework> element net45 -->
          <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)projectxyz.props"/>    
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
          <!-- it has <TargetFramework> element netcoreapp2.0-->
          <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)projectAbc.props"/>
        </Otherwise>
      </Choose>

   </Project>
```

Vs2017 fail to load the project with errors:

```
    error  : The element <Import> beneath element <When> is unrecognized.   
    error  : The element <Import> beneath element <Otherwise> is unrecognized.
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Maybe conditional imports aren't allowed via Choose? Using `<Import Condition="..." Project="..."` works though.

Comment: While conditional import statements work in command-line MSBuilds, they do not work with MSBuild in the Visual Studio (IDE), ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017

Comment: @M.Hassan, It seems the Choose element is not supported by the new SDK style project currently. The method I use now is like stijn said `<Import Condition="..." Project="..."`. Do you mean it not work for you in the VS IDE? Have you check the path and variables are correct? It works fine on my side.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT,@ stijn, Every project has `<TargetFramework>` element. I used import with condition, but the error message changed to `The TargetFramework value '' was not recognized`. So I'm not sure if the imported project is loaded correctly.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT,@ stijn, I used import with condition as you said. I run msbuild /t:restore then msbuild /t:build. It works fine from commandline. But in Vs IDE it fail. So Conclusion: 1)Choose  element is not supporting import. 2)import with condition work fine using msbuild commandline Not VS2017 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question that was literally asked: *What's wrong with this code?*

The answer is that this code does not conform to the MSBuild file schema.

According to the [MSBuild Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2017), **Import** is not an allowed child of **When** or **Otherwise**. Only **PropertyGroup**, **ItemGroup** and **Choose** are allowed.

Now, if what you were actually trying to ask is "How do I conditionally import a project?", then post that question.